# Как реализовать появление блока при нажатии на кнопку? JS

Tags: javascript, html, события

Нужно, чтоб при нажатии на кнопку "Редактировать", вместо `li` c надписью "Hello" и кнопками появлялся `input` и кнопочка "Сохранить".

`addEventListener` уже поставил, но не могу понять через что, или как заменять содержимое `li`?

Пишу на чистом JS, поэтому реализовать нужно на нем (jQuery использовать нельзя).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример от которого Вы можете оттолкнуться:

```js
const handleEditClick = () => {
  document.querySelector(".wrapper-one").classList.add("hide")
  document.querySelector(".wrapper-two").classList.remove("hide")
}

document.querySelector(".edit").addEventListener("click", handleEditClick)

const handleSaveClick = () => {
  console.log("сохранено")
}

document.querySelector(".save").addEventListener("click", handleSaveClick)
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-one">
  <li>Hello</li>
  <button class="edit">Редактировать</button>  
</div>

<div class="wrapper-two hide">
  <input />
  <button class="save">Сохранить</button>  
</div>
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, забыл упомянуть, что я все пишу на чистом JS...

Comment: @Torin_21 а здесь что то "не чисто"?

Comment: На моей странице исходной не должно быть ничего кроме html, head, body

Comment: @Torin_21 `На моей странице исходной не должно быть ничего кроме html, head, body` а как это связано с моим ответом? Вы можете разместить данный скрипт в любом нужном для Вас месте